# Pre-Populating Paypal billing form phone field

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout

I'm using Express Checkout PHP-SDK (release 96) in my web app.

I'm trying to prefill my customer's billing details on Paypal.

```
$address                  = new AddressType();
$address->CityName        = strtoupper_tr( $order['invoice']['address']['city'] );
$address->Name            = $order['invoice']['title'];
$address->Street1         = $order['invoice']['address']['address'];
$address->Street2         = $order['invoice']['address']['address-2'];
$address->StateOrProvince = $order['invoice']['address']['province'];
$address->PostalCode      = $order['invoice']['address']['postal-code'];
$address->Country         = 'TR';
$address->Phone           = '5004244244';

...

$set_ec_req_details                 = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType();
$set_ec_req_details->BillingAddress = $address;
```

This code populate form except Phone Number.
I find that if I change country code to 'US', it works too.

I could not find any information on x.com's forums or documentations. I'll be grateful if someone tell me there is a way to do this or not.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with this cart, but Paypals phone codes are very much US centric but I've had good luck using night_phone_b to place the phone number into.

Details are https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_xclick_prepopulate_outside